# xml with strings and int android studio how to read int as String

Tags: java, android, arrays, xml

I am trying to read a xml file with strings and int, and the array I get only have the strings, where there is supposed to be a int , it shows null...
this is my xml file arrays.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<array name="questionnaire">
    <item>Quelle est la capital du Venezuela?</item>
    <item>4</item>
    <item>Maracay</item>
    <item>Caracas</item>
    <item>Valencia</item>
    <item>San Cristobal</item>
    <item>2</item>
</array>
</resources>
```

this is my java code

```
typeQuestion = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.questionnaire);
```

I thought my array typeQuestion would get the number 4 and 2 as strings, but it doesnt do it, that position is null in the array.....what can i do , to get the 4 and 2 as strings in the array??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use both string and int in `String.xml` file means  use
**string-array** instead of **array** .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string-array name="questionnaire">
<item>Quelle est la capital du Venezuela?</item>
<item>4</item>
<item>Maracay</item>
<item>Caracas</item>
<item>Valencia</item>
<item>San Cristobal</item>
<item>2</item>
</resources>
</string-array>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
    <string-array name="questionnaire">
    <item>Quelle est la capital du Venezuela?</item>
            <item>4</item>
            <item>Maracay</item>
            <item>Caracas</item>
            <item>Valencia</item>
            <item>San Cristobal</item>
            <item>2</item>
   </string-array>
   </resources>
```

Use string-array instead of using only array in the resources as then the integers entered by you will also be read as string and hence will be visible when you get the resource